# JPA entity responsibility in domain driven design

Tags: java, jpa, domain-driven-design, single-responsibility-principle

I am wondering if JPA entity and DDD entity should be the same class?
I can see in examples that it is a common practice, but doesn't it violate single responsibility principle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this to be common practice due to a level of convenience but it's not particularly clean design. In most cases it's coincidental that the JPA entities match, or are at least close enough, to domain objects.

JPA is an abstraction to the persistent data layer and its core focus is providing an object to relational data mapping. The JPA entities therefore really only represent object hierarchies of the **data** model.

It may well be that your domain objects consist of only elements that are represented and stored within a persistent data store and this would feel somewhat like duplication if creating both domain and JPA entities that contain the exact same data structures.

True domain objects live at the center of the application's architecture where all dependencies point towards them and this would also include the data layer.  I would always recommend this approach purely as it clarifies the actual intent for the architectural boundaries.

Edit.
To answer your second part of the question on SRP violation in JPA - it depends.  The responsibilities (in SRP) do tend to match relational tables since we tend to logically group related data together (think Account table, or Contact table).  This does fall down in JPA more often though when thinking about relationships (Employee -> Salary).

Comment: Agree with this. In the long term, table names, column names, relationships, etc. invariably change. If that means that the domain layer needs to be altered too, dependencies are not pointing in the right direction. It's worthwhile to start correctly and maintain the two separately. As a side note, an interesting pattern I have used in the past is to dynamically generate the JPA class from DDD Entity class if they both have the same structure. But this depends on the ORM you use, the markup for the database schema, etc.

Comment: A practical issue here is - how do u do things like optimistic version control in this model ? Say u have a domain service that does read-->update-->save on a domain model . Now the jpa entity might have a version column that it can't pass upwards. Thus when the save call comes to the repo and the repo essentially once again does ( model --> entity) conversion and read+update , it will have now way to tell which  version of entity was read originally. That and a few extra reads here .

Answer (score 3):

> I am wondering if JPA entity and DDD entity should be the same class? I can see in examples that it is a common practice, but doesn't it violate single responsibility principle?

You may want to review [Classes vs Data Structures](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2019/06/16/ObjectsAndDataStructures.html), by Robert Martin.

I would normally expect JPA entities to be "anemic bags of data"; they are essentially *messages* written in the past to be consumed in the future.

Domain Model Entities, on the other hand, are not anemic - they have direct understanding of how to mutate their own data structures in accordance with the rules of the domain in which they serve.

In the DDD book, Evans describes using the "factory" pattern to create an instance of a domain entity from raw data.  That pattern fits equally well with creating a domain entity from a jpa entity.

The transformation in the other direction -- taking a domain entity and extracting from it the data you need to save, is *not* clearly addressed, but the mechanics are the same.  You read data out of your domain entity, and write it into your jpa entity (whether or you writing into a new jpa entity, or updating one that already exists, will depend on the details of your persistence strategy).

You aren't guaranteed to make a mess if you try to make the two entities "the same", but there are definitely different concerns.

For example, our persistent representation of data is expected to have a life cycle that spans many releases, new versions of our domain model are supposed to be to work our previously stored data.  At the same time, we should be able to change the data structures that we use inside the domain model freely.  Semantically, it's the same information, but the pressures on structure and organization are very different.

Comment: JPA entities don’t have to be anemic.